# How to exchange OAUTH token ( Go ) using Google API

Tags: oauth, go, google-oauth

Here is what I have so far which returns a "400 error". Am I doing something wrong? I can't figure it out why is not working as the request is pretty straightforward

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    cachefile := "cache.json"
    code := "4/xxxxx.8uFT5Z0slpMbJvIeHux6iLY_9k7ajw" //the code received from the URL redirect
    // Set up a configuration.
    config := &oauth.Config{
        ClientId:     "xx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        ClientSecret: "cWP3HudD3XmaP33j8",
        RedirectURL:  "https://crm.com/sender/gmail/auth/callBack",
        Scope:        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
        AuthURL:      "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        TokenURL:     "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        AccessType:   "offline",
        TokenCache:   oauth.CacheFile(cachefile),
    }

    // Set up a Transport using the config.
    transport := &oauth.Transport{Config: config}
    token, err := config.TokenCache.Token()
    if err != nil {
        token, err = transport.Exchange(code)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Exchange:", err)
        }
    }
    // (The Exchange method will automatically cache the token.)

    transport.Token = token
    fmt.Println(token)
}
```

**Result**

```
Exchange:OAuthError: updateToken: Unexpected HTTP status 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: You've got an access code hard coded in your program.  These are single use, so is it possible that you had already used the token?

Comment: You are right... I thought the "code" it's actually the refresh token.

Comment: Right.  The code is what is passed to your redirect URL through the user's web browser when they authenticate to the service.  You use that single use code to create a multi-use access token.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use 'one-time code flow', as described [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow?hl=en):

> To take advantage of all of the benefits of Google+ Sign-In you must use a hybrid server-side flow where a user authorizes your app on the client side using the JavaScript API client and you send a special one-time authorization code to your server. Your server exchanges this one-time-use code to acquire its own access and refresh tokens from Google for the server to be able to make its own API calls, which can be done while the user is offline. This one-time code flow has security advantages over both a pure server-side flow and over sending access tokens to your server.

As code can be used just once there are less chances of compromising user's account.

Client code is pretty straight forward, follow the example [in step 3](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#step_3_include_the_google_script_on_your_page).

For server-side, I would recommend using the package [oauth2](https://github.com/golang/oauth2) instead of `goauth2`.

```
$ go get code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/plus/v1
$ go get github.com/golang/oauth2
$ go get google.golang.org/appengine
```

For some reason, `oauth2` package requires also `appengine` package.

Exchanging the one-time code for a reusable token can be done using function [NewTransportWithCode](http://godoc.org/github.com/golang/oauth2#Config.NewTransportWithCode):

```
func exchangeCode(code string) (*oauth2.Token, *oauth2.Transport, error) {
    config, err := google.NewConfig(&oauth2.Options{
        ClientID:     CLIENT_ID,
        ClientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        RedirectURL:  "postmessage",
        Scopes:       []string{"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"},
    })
    if err != nil {
        return &oauth2.Token{}, &oauth2.Transport{}, err
    }

    transport, err := config.NewTransportWithCode(code)
    if err != nil {
        return &oauth2.Token{}, &oauth2.Transport{}, err
    }

    token := transport.Token()
    return token, transport, nil
}
```

And finally the code you created in step 3 can submit one time code to a handler listening at `/oauth2`:

```
func oauth2Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // TODO Check request has...
    // - Method: POST
    // - Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8
    // - CSRF Token http://goo.gl/mNCjJm

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    defer r.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    code := string(body[:])
    token, transport, err := exchangeCode(code)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // From here you can use the transport
    client := http.Client{Transport: transport}
    service, err := plus.New(&client)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
    person, err := service.People.Get("me").Do()
    // ...
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/oauth2", oauth2Handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}
```

Some error handling is missing, but you get the idea.

Comment: what is the redirectURL value in google.NewConfig for???

Comment: answer is from 2014... I recommend you check the documentation, it probably changed several times already